# Jquery width() Function Doesn't Return The Full Width of My Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get full size of my window(browser) which is 1366px. I use jquery width() function to achieve this. But It returns 1349px instead of 1366px. Therefore my slider appears 17px less than it should be. What did I do wrong you guys think?

```
var theWithObj = $('body').width();
console.log(theWithObj); //It returns 1349 but actual 100% size is 1366
```

Thank you!

Comment: When I start a new site, first thing `*{box-sizing: border-box}`.

Comment: I tried but it returns the same value 1349

Comment: What is the padding/margin on the body/html?

Comment: Is it really 1366? The scrollbar is usually around 16px, 1349 sounds about right.

Comment: Where are you getting 1366 from?

Comment: Uhh you're right! It is allocated for scrollbar. How could I overcome this. But I do not want scrollbar to appear.

Comment: padding,margin 0 @KevinB

Comment: A Thousand Thanks! @elclanrs I set it "auto". Fixed it to hidden.

Comment: The jquery API tells you all about this: http://api.jquery.com/width/ Read the docs!

Comment: @epascarello I did read that! My problem was about the overflow and we fixed it here. Thanks for your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(window).width();
```

If that's still not 1366 then you've probably calculated that number incorrectly - if you think you've calculated it correctly and jQuery's still wrong then please tell us how you came to find the width as 1366 :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$(window).width()` will give you the width of the browser (with or without srollbars)

If you use only $`('body').width()`, you'll get the width of the page only (so the width of the browser minus the width of the scrollbars.

```
alert($(window).width());
alert($('body').width());
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9PnB9/1)

Answer (score 0):

For solve the problem add this rule css:

```
body {overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained why it fixes the problem. Also you may want to add why someone would want to use this method rather than the existing answers.